# table in json data returning as undefined but has data

Tags: jquery

I'm fetching some data from a URL - the data looks like this

```
{"Success":true,"Table":[{"yrmo":"2018-05","enrolled":5,"notenrolled":0},{"yrmo":"2018-06","enrolled":4,"notenrolled":0},{"yrmo":"2018-07","enrolled":8,"notenrolled":0},{"yrmo":"2018-08","enrolled":7,"notenrolled":0},{"yrmo":"2018-09","enrolled":7,"notenrolled":1},{"yrmo":"2018-10","enrolled":0,"notenrolled":0}],"Information":"OK"}
```

I load that into "data" and I output it to console and I can see the data just fine

```
console.log(data);
```

which returns

```
{Success: true, Table: Array(6), Information: "OK"}
```

And if I send data.Table to the console, that works too:

```
console.log(data.Table);
```

which returns like this:

```
(6) [(...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
```

Expanding that out shows:

```
0: {yrmo: "2018-05", enrolled: 5, notenrolled: 0}
1: {yrmo: "2018-06", enrolled: 4, notenrolled: 0}
2: {yrmo: "2018-07", enrolled: 8, notenrolled: 0}
3: {yrmo: "2018-08", enrolled: 7, notenrolled: 0}
4: {yrmo: "2018-09", enrolled: 7, notenrolled: 1}
5: {yrmo: "2018-10", enrolled: 0, notenrolled: 0}
```

All is as I would expect - then I try and use $.each to loop through each item

```
$.each(data.Table, function(i, item) {
   console.log(item);
});
```

(I've also tried sending item.yrmo, item.enrolled and item.notenrolled to console in the same manner with the same result)

At which point it breaks and says "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined at Test.aspx:60"

Which is the $.each line - I'm at a loss as to why it thinks it is undefined when it clearly isn't.

I was able to get it working by trying another route:

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.Table.length; j++){
    var q = data.Table[j];
    console.log(q.yrmo);
    console.log(q.enrolled);
    console.log(q.notenrolled);
}
```

And this allowed me to output my values - but I'm at a loss as to why the $.each isn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the whole code. It sounds like you're not running `$.each` inside the proper callback function.

Comment: If you call `$.each` at the same place in the code as the `for` loop, it should work the same.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'each' of undefined` sounds like `$` isn't defined. Are you sure you loaded jQuery properly?

Comment: Paul Abbott - 2+ hours of bashing my head against the wall and that was it. I'm using a test page which didn't have the load on there.  Man i feel stupid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Paul Abbott pointed out that jquery wasn't correctly loaded..  I was using a test page and it didn't even occur to me to check.

Corrected that and ran and it worked fine.

Thanks Paul - I'd mark you as correct if I could!